# ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined | Next.js

Tags: reactjs, onclick, accordion

I'm getting a ***ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined*** error in my React code, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here is the code that's causing the error:

```
const services = [
  {
    title: (
      <AccordionHeader>
        <AccordionLeft>
          <span>01</span>
        </AccordionLeft>
        <AccordionRight className="icon-container">
          <p>Project Name</p>
          <BsArrowRight
            onClick={handleClick}
            className={`icon ${rotate ? "rotate" : ""}`}
          />
        </AccordionRight>
      </AccordionHeader>
    ),
    content: <>{/* CODE */}</>
  }
];

const ProjectsPage = () => {
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setRotate(!rotate);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {services.map((services, index) => (
        <>
          <Accordion
            key={index}
            title={services.title}
            content={services.content}
          />
          <HrLine />
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProjectsPage;
```

I have defined the **handleClick** function within the component, but I'm still getting this error. How can I fix this issue?

My error is:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you *define* `services`, `handleClick` is indeed not defined.  It only exists within the scope of the `ProjectsPage` component.

Move the definition of `services` to within the component.:

```
const ProjectsPage = () => {
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setRotate(!rotate);
  };

  const services = ... // <-- here
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep it outside the component, make it a function and pass it the value it needs.  For example:

```
const services = (handleClick) => [
  //...
];
```

And then in the component:

```
{services(handleClick).map((services, index) => (
```